# How to install cub linux OS and remove ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, laptop

If I wanna completely remove ubuntu(**16.04**, the only OS on my laptop) and install the **cub linux** OS on my **laptop**. How can I do it with ease probably with USB or in any other simple way?

Regards

Comment: Just install Cub Linux and tell it to use the entire hard drive. No need to uninstall Ubuntu.

Comment: So, its just downloading the iso file, opening it and following the process? @NickWeinberg

Comment: No, you need to use the ISO file to create a bootable USB stick or DVD.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While Nick already answered your question - i'll add an answer to let you "close" the case as answered.

You should follow the instructions offered by the [CUB project page](https://cublinux.com/download/).

In short:

- download the iso
- verify the download
- create a bootable usb
- install using the entire harddrive

The installation process itself is described [here](https://cublinux.com/wiki/doku.php?id=installation) as well. In your case choose the option **Erase and (re)install**

Good luck.